# In pydroid3, I have installed pywhatkit5.4 using pip menu. But, import pywhatkit in program fails

Tags: python, pydroid

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.whats import (
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pywhatkit/whats.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

[Program finished]
```

import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg ("+9195352xxxx5",  "Hello ",  14, 10)
pywhatkit not getting imported in this 2 line program. Above is the error message.